# JNI Method not working in getting package name from a class

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am getting package name from a class object in cpp file in Android studio. It is working fine on all phone except Huwaeis phones.

**Below is code**

```
jclass android_content_Context = env->GetObjectClass(activity);
jmethodID midGetPackageName = env->GetMethodID(android_content_Context, "getPackageName$",
                                               "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring packageName = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(activity, midGetPackageName);
```

**Below is the stack trace.**

```
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: mid == null
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]     in call to CallObjectMethodV
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]     from java.lang.String com.test.example.utils.JNIMapperUtil.getStringForKey(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x75358f78 self=0x7659214c00
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | sysTid=13440 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x76df89d548
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | state=R schedstat=( 1259145841 188058850 2907 ) utm=94 stm=30 core=4 HZ=100
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | stack=0x7fd0905000-0x7fd0907000 stackSize=8MB
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #00 pc 00000000003c7d4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+220)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #01 pc 00000000004a5af0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+352)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #02 pc 00000000002e98a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+968)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #03 pc 000000000033822c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallObjectMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+1636)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #04 pc 000000000000dcbc  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/lib/arm64/libpaymentslib.so (_JNIEnv::CallObjectMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+116)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #05 pc 000000000000dba4  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/lib/arm64/libpaymentslib.so (Java_ae_sdg_librarypayment_utils_JNIMapperUtil_getStringForKey+108)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #06 pc 00000000000df0e8  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset df000) (ae.gov.dsg.utils.JNIMapperUtil.getStringForKey [DEDUPED]+200)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #07 pc 000000000056f24c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #08 pc 00000000000d4224  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #09 pc 0000000000283fa8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #10 pc 000000000027dfb0  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+968)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #11 pc 000000000053ff28  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #12 pc 0000000000561714  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #13 pc 000000000039f7b0  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.test.example.utils.JNIMapperUtil.a+4)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #14 pc 0000000000257cb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.1977376047+488)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #15 pc 000000000052aa14  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1020)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #16 pc 00000000005780fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #17 pc 000000000056f24c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #18 pc 00000000000d4224  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #19 pc 0000000000283fa8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #20 pc 000000000027dfb0  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+968)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #21 pc 000000000053ff28  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #22 pc 0000000000561714  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #23 pc 000000000039f52a  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.test.example.w.data.client.decryptKey+8)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #24 pc 0000000000257cb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.1977376047+488)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #25 pc 000000000025d7a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #26 pc 000000000027df94  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+940)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #27 pc 000000000053ff28  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #28 pc 0000000000561714  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #29 pc 000000000039f6c2  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.test.example.w.data.client.<init>+4)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #30 pc 0000000000257cb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.1977376047+488)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #31 pc 000000000025d7a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #32 pc 000000000027df94  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+940)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #33 pc 000000000053fd64  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+296)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #34 pc 0000000000561694  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #35 pc 000000000039ebb6  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.test.example.mwallet.business.a$1.<init>+4)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #36 pc 0000000000257cb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.1977376047+488)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #37 pc 000000000025d7a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #38 pc 000000000027df94  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+940)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #39 pc 000000000053fd64  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+296)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #40 pc 0000000000561694  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #41 pc 000000000039f0fa  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.test.example.mwallet.business.a.<init>+30)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #42 pc 0000000000257cb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.1977376047+488)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #43 pc 000000000025d7a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #44 pc 000000000027df94  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+940)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #45 pc 000000000053fd64  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+296)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #46 pc 0000000000561694  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #47 pc 00000000002de29e  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.test.example.fe.a.b.<init>+70)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #48 pc 0000000000257cb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.1977376047+488)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #49 pc 000000000025d7a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #50 pc 000000000027df94  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+940)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #51 pc 000000000053fd64  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+296)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #52 pc 0000000000561694  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #53 pc 00000000002de574  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.test.example.fe.a.B+12)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #54 pc 0000000000257cb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.1977376047+488)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #55 pc 000000000025d7a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #56 pc 000000000027df94  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+940)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #57 pc 000000000053fd64  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+296)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #58 pc 0000000000561694  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #59 pc 00000000002de634  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.test.example.fe.a.a)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #60 pc 0000000000257cb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.1977376047+488)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #61 pc 000000000025d7a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #62 pc 000000000027df94  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+940)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #63 pc 000000000053ff28  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #64 pc 0000000000561714  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
12-27 11:34:30.197 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #65 pc 00000000002dd860  /data/app/com.test.example-J18lJKR8ELvqbQgrCVjYLQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.test.example.fe.a$1.onClick+4)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #66 pc 0000000000257cb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.1977376047+488)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #67 pc 000000000052aa14  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1020)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #68 pc 00000000005780fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #69 pc 0000000000d67a7c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 413000) (android.view.View.performClick+284)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #70 pc 0000000000c8c1dc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 413000) (android.view.View$PerformClick.run+236)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #71 pc 0000000000bad0bc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 413000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+76)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #72 pc 0000000000bb04ac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 413000) (android.os.Looper.loop+1436)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #73 pc 0000000000947cf4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 413000) (android.app.ActivityThread.main+1236)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #74 pc 000000000056f24c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #75 pc 00000000000d4224  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #76 pc 0000000000472f60  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #77 pc 00000000004749b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1440)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #78 pc 0000000000404338  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #79 pc 00000000001456d4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 13b000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+180)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #80 pc 0000000000eda5a8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 413000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+136)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #81 pc 0000000000ee147c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 413000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2540)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #82 pc 000000000056f24c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #83 pc 00000000000d4224  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #84 pc 0000000000472f60  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #85 pc 0000000000472bc0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+424)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #86 pc 0000000000367254  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+652)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #87 pc 00000000000b92c0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+120)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #88 pc 00000000000bbee4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+780)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #89 pc 0000000000002368  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1444)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #90 pc 00000000000adf40  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.utils.JNIMapperUtil.getStringForKey(Native method)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.utils.JNIMapperUtil.a(SourceFile:12)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.w.data.client.getKey(SourceFile:56)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.w.data.client.<init>(SourceFile:61)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.mwallet.business.a$1.<init>(SourceFile:113)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.mwallet.business.a.<init>(SourceFile:113)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.fe.a.b.<init>(SourceFile:37)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.fe.a.B(SourceFile:419)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.fe.a.a(SourceFile:52)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.test.example.fe.a$1.onClick(SourceFile:89)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6653)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6625)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:786)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26223)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7470)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
12-27 11:34:30.198 13440 13440 F com.test.example: java_vm_ext.cc:542] 
12-27 11:34:30.231 13440 13440 F com.test.example: thread.cc:2164] No pending exception expected: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/lang/Class;.getPackageName$()Ljava/lang/String;"
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `getPackageName$` instead of `getPackageName` (without the dollar sign)?

Comment: Please post a [**M**inimal, **C**omplete, **V**erfiable **E**xample.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  From the code you've posted, you aren't doing *any* error checking, which is a really, really, **REALLY** bad idea in JNI.